# How to shorten Excel's time of "waiting for the query to be executed" while pulling data from a third party MySQL?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mysql

I use Excel files which pull data from MySQL via MySQL's Download Connector/ODBC (MySQL's official Excel plugin).
Whenever it connects to the remote MySQL server (on Google Apps), Excel gets stuck for like 2-5 minutes with the status bar message "waiting for the query to be executed".

Once the 2-5 minutes are up, it starts pulling data both in the background and very fast, which is great.
But isn't there any way to shorten the 2-5 minutes?

Thanks!

I use Windows 7 & 8.1 with Office 2010-2016.

Comment: probably that time is necessary to download the data and after processing it on your pc is quicker. Without knowing more details I can't really tell more.

Comment: Try the answer to this StackOverflow - connecting to MySQL server so slow - Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292856/why-is-connecting-to-mysql-server-so-slow